# Check to see if toolstripmenuitem is checked

Tags: c#

```cs
    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (clearHistoryOnQuitToolStripMenuItem.Checked)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255");
        }

    }
```

**I don't get any errors but the program still performs the action inside the if statement even if the Item is unchecked.**

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with what you have done implementing the `if` statement, so there must be an issue with something external to what you have provided above.

- Is the MenuItem checked OR indeterminate (both return true when `Checked` is queried)

  - See - [ToolStripMenuItem.Checked Property (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem.checked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- Is the MenuItem actually toggling (wrong property settings etc.)

Just be sure of the `Checked` state prior to entering the `if` statement before you go any further... You may find your answer right then and there.

Try the following and see what writes to the console when run.

```
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(clearHistoryOnQuitToolStripMenuItem.CheckState.ToString());
        if (clearHistoryOnQuitToolStripMenuItem.Checked)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255");
        }

    }
```

Best of luck & at least from here you will be able to figure out why your `Checked` state is always returning true (or is it!)...